# Picture Library - Downloading images in different formats

Tags: picture-library

I am currently developing a digital media library for a university and I have hundreds of images to upload to our SharePoint site. Initially I was uploading an original image, tiff file, a high resolution jpg and a web size jpg. However, I was informed that it is possible to upload one format, such as the large design file, and then allow for users to select a variation of downloadable options. ie; HR jpg, tiff, web ect.

I would like to know how I can make this possible, so I can avoid having 3-4 of the same images in the library. I am using the SharePoint 2016/2019 online version.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can configure something called "Image Renditions" which is available in SharePoint. This allows you to allow to render a single image into multiple sizes or dimensions. PFB the link to Microsoft doc on how to create an image rendition. Hope it helps!

[How to add Image renditions ?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-image-renditions)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! Amazing!

Comment: @ellen89 Glad, it helped. Please upvote the answer if it was useful. Let us know if you have any queries.